# Basic JavaScript Issue: Targeting a Specific Div in DOM and Changing Properties

Tags: javascript

I am not great with JavaScript, and I am thinking this is a fairly easy answer.

Link to project:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4132989/example02/example02/index.html

What I'm trying to do:
Make the draggable cell turn red, and the text turn white, when it's dropped to it's correct location.

When I drag the green or orange cell to their correct locations, I have inserted this as a test to make sure I am able to target only when the drag is correct.

document.body.style.background="red"

If you look at the code, on drop, the border changes on the cell from solid, to dotted. What I am trying to do is be able to change any property on drop. I want to make the background of the cell red on drop and I'd like the text to turn white. I tried this:

REDIPS.drag.style.background="red"

However, this did not work and it made everything non-draggable.

To download the code use this link:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4132989/example02.zip

Thanks in advance for any help.

*Oh, the change I made is in the file redips-drag-min.js

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but the object you really want to change is `rd.target_cell`, the cell that just received the drop action. Add the following inside the `if (rd.target_cell.className ...` conditional (line 31 of script.js):

```
rd.target_cell.style.background= 'red';
```

Comment: Hey, that worked! :D Thanks.

Only 1 issue. I meant I wanted to change the draggable object background, not the cell it gets dropped into. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: I got it! :D

rd.obj.style.background= 'red';

Comment: Looks like I have 1 more question... 

rd.obj.style.font-size= '2px';

How would I change font-size? This does not work.

Comment: Try `rd.obj.style['font-size'] = '2px';`.